# How to replace valve cartridge on Kohler DevonshireWidespread bathroom sink faucet

Tags: faucet, sink

The cold faucet is leaking, and I am trying to repair it by replacing the valve cartridge. However, for the love of god, I can't find a way to open the faucet so that I can replace the valve cartridge. I don't see a small opening anywhere and I can't seem to remove any top or tip of the faucet. I tried to unscrew the handle, but I am stuck afterwards. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://www.us.kohler.com/us/Devonshire-widespread-bathroom-sink-faucet-with-lever-handles/productDetail/sink-faucets/421739.htm

[image]

Comment: have you watched the "how to replace the cartridge" video on the web page that you linked?

Comment: It's a generic video, so the faucet featured there is not this particular faucet.

Answer (score 2):

unscrew the nut under the sink and then you can turn the lever counter clockwise, sometimes there is plumbers putty that makes it hard to unscrew the lever without taking the nut under the sink off, watch this link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc7Q5666yoU

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

Give Kohler a call. All their products carry a lifetime warranty or at least they used to, They can explain the procedure you are looking for and send you the repair parts free to you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on kohler you unscrew the pedestal. On cold put a cloth around the pedestal use pliers turning counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Pour CLR on a rag and wrap it around the faucet handle. Give it a couple of hours. The calcium has built up and that is not letting you simply unscrew the handle.

Got this from Kohler.